# Scala implicit ambiguous example modification not throwing compile error

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm trying to implement an implicit `Not[T]` in Scala, and as such I want to throw an compiler error when there is an implicit val in scope of type `T`. I thought of doing this using ambiguous implicits as the Scaladoc shows a way to implement `=!=`. (See below)

But, I don't understand why two `newAmbig`s are necessary, because there still seems to be an ambiguous implicit if I remove one, as there originally seems to be 3 viable implicits. (See below)

I could not find any documentation on what is required for the compiler to flag an ambiguous implicit.

The implementation of `=!=` shown by the Scaladoc:

```
trait =!=[C, D]

implicit def neq[E, F] : E =!= F = null

@annotation.implicitAmbiguous("Could not prove ${J} =!= ${J}")
implicit def neqAmbig1[G, H, J] : J =!= J = null
implicit def neqAmbig2[I] : I =!= I = null

implicitly[Int =!= Int]
```

The implementation of `=!=` that seems to work but does not:

```
trait =!=[C, D]

implicit def neq[E, F] : E =!= F = null

@annotation.implicitAmbiguous("Could not prove ${J} =!= ${J}")
implicit def neqAmbig1[G, H, J] : J =!= J = null

implicitly[Int =!= Int]
```

As both the `neqAmbig1` and `neq` should be of the same type, and both should be found.

But, this doesn't throw a compiler error, and when tested, just returns `null`.

Answer (score 2):

[isAsSpecific](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6b4d32c3f518d21a798e8d3cf4a8c35866afa8e2/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer.scala#L858) seems to be the relevant part of the compiler that codifies overloading resolution rules from the spec, so see if you can decipher those:

```
/** Is type `ftpe1` strictly more specific than type `ftpe2`
 *  when both are alternatives in an overloaded function?
 *  @see SLS (sec:overloading-resolution)
 */
 def isAsSpecific(ftpe1: Type, ftpe2: Type): Boolean
```

To confirm your first implementation is correct consider [Type inequality](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/0cc1d28df5e09962ab4aa59402fc77d9e5560a66/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L40) as provided by shapeless

```
// Type inequalities
trait =:!=[A, B] extends Serializable
implicit def neq[A, B] : A =:!= B = new =:!=[A, B] {}
implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A =:!= A = unexpected
implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A =:!= A = unexpected
```

For example,

```
import shapeless.{<:!<, =:!=}

def foo[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A =:!= String): A = a

foo(3)  // ok
foo("") // error: ambiguous implicit values
```

Comment: My question is why is it necessary for there to be two neqAmbigs. Why can't it just be replaced with one?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by simplifying and clarifying the situation.

This works. The implicit is resolved as expected.

```scala
trait =!=[C, D]

implicit def neq[E, F] : E =!= F =
  new =!=[E,F]{override def toString="NEQ"}

implicitly[Int =!= Int]  //res0: Int =!= Int = NEQ
```

Now let's add what *should be* an ambiguous implicit.

```scala
trait =!=[C, D]

implicit def neq[E, F] : E =!= F =
  new =!=[E,F]{override def toString="NEQ"}

implicit def neqAmbig1[E, F] : E =!= E =
  new =!=[E,E]{override def toString="NeqAm1"}

implicitly[Int =!= Int]  //res0: Int =!= Int = NeqAm1
```

Hmmm. In the case of `Int =!= Int` we have `E` as `Int`, and `F` as `Int`, so type `E =!= F` should be the same as `E =!= E`, and yet the compiler does not consider them to be equivalent and chooses the `E =!= E` version (no matter what order the implicits are defined in the code).

I believe what's going on here is described in the [language spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html):

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules of static overloading resolution.

This is from the section on Implicit Parameters but I think it still applies: type `E =!= E` is more specific to `Int =!= Int` than type `E =!= F` is.